# Which method is more efficient for upper case text: CSS or PHP?

Tags: php, css, css-selectors

**Which method is more efficient for rendering upper case text: CSS or PHP?**

a. PHP

```
<?php
echo strtoupper("Test"); //  TEST
?>
```

b. CSS

```
<style type="text/css">.uppercase { text-transform: uppercase; }</style>
<div class="uppercase">Test</div>
```

Comment: Both efficient, depends on if you want to use your server for that or the user's browser.

Comment: By efficiency you mean the chance of failure when you run it? I think both css and php convert text to upper case in 100% occasions.

Comment: Separation of concerns: PHP handles content, CSS handles styling. Which category do you think it belongs in?

Comment: I would always choose client's CPU/GPU over server's wherever you can. Effect is the same but your server has less work to do. Small work on client's machine is multiplied by many users if done on server's side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real efficiency difference in terms of rendering the content. One is rendered on the server by PHP. The other is rendered in the browser with CSS.

There is one general efficiency matter you may want to consider.

With PHP, you're converting a single string to uppercase. If you have other strings to convert, you'll need to repeat the function each time.

With CSS, you can target all text you want uppercased with a single selector.

In that respect, I would say CSS is more efficient, as it is simpler, scalable and easier to maintain.

Also, assuming CSS handles other text styles, such as `font-size`, `font-family`, `font-weight`, `font-style`, `color` and `letter-spacing`, then why not include `text-transform` in that group?

Why single out one style to be handled by PHP and the rest handled by CSS?

Unless it is, for whatever reason, essential to have PHP handle the uppercase transformation, you should assign all styling tasks to CSS.

Answer (score 5):

Both ways are just as *efficient*: given any input, both ways will convert the input to a capitalized output with an equal amount of steps (assuming similar implementations, i.e. [O(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).

However, the question you should ask isn't whether both are as efficient; the question is whether you want your server to be responsible for transforming text to uppercase for **styling** purposes.

The answer to this is: of course not, [that's CSS' job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Letting the client (browser) handle the text transformation removes one instruction (per request) from your server and keeps client/server responsibilities separate.

One instruction might not change much now, but that's not always the case. Keeping client/server responsibilities separate helps keep code clean. :)

It also has the upside @Michael_B mentioned, which is that you can target multiple strings more easily with CSS selectors than by manually transforming them with PHP.